# Remove duplicate arraylists from an arraylist

Tags: arraylist

```
for (int i = 0; i < todos.size(); i++) {
    for (int j = i + 1; j < todos.size(); j++) {
        cont = 0;

        for (int k = 0; k < todos.get(i).size(); k++) {
            if (todos.get(i).get(k) == todos.get(j).get(k)) {
                cont++;
                if (cont == todos.get(i).size()) {
                    todos.remove(j);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Does it work? It was tested but I don't know....is this correct?

Comment: You need to tell us more about what you're doing and what problems you're having. A good way to find out if your code works is to run it and find out! Also you should tag your post with the programming language (this looks like Java?).

Answer (score 0):

This should Do it.

```
public void addTodo(Para){
Boolean add=true;
for (int j = 0; j < todos.size(); j++) {
if(Para==todo.get(j)) 
add=false;
}
if(add == true)
todo.add(Para);
}
```

Comment: I think you can format it better, also your method is not valid since you only have parameter type.

Comment: I don't Know what his parameter is. For a list I could be anything.

Comment: That's a good practice to indent and write brackets even if one-lined, then, I'm not sure that you can compare everything with `==`. Also, this could be simplified : `if (add==true)` is pretty much the same as `if (add)`. Don't be hasty :-)